# how to run a file not using typing ./filename but just typing $anyword?

Tags: unix

I have wrote a file called "list"

```
#!/bin/bash
while echo Player name?
      read name
      [ $name != "ZZZ" ]
do
    while echo 'See target (T/t) or team name (M/m)? '
         read word
         [ $word != "t" -a $word != "T" -a $word != "m" -a $word != "M" ]
   do
         echo Please enter only T or M.
   done

   if [ $word = "t" -o $word = "T" ]
   then
      grep $name emplist | cut -c44-58
   else
      grep $name emplist | cut -c31-43
   fi
done
```

but every time I run it I should use **./list**, if I want to type **$search** to run it, What should I write in the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either make a [symlink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link#POSIX_and_Unix-like_operating_systems) from say `/usr/bin/$search` to your `list` file or use an alias.

```
ln -s /home/user/list /usr/bin/$search
```

or

```
# add to .bashrc or similar
alias $search=/home/user/list
```

For me it makes more sense to use the full path to the `list` file, however if you want to use relative paths then option one is out if the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want `$search` to have the same effect as running your script `./list` then you can set variable `search` in your shell to `./list`:

```
$ search=./list
$ $search # this will expand to ./list (that's the value of your $search variable)
```

I guess it will be more useful if you do:

```
$ search=/ful/path/to/list
```